# Is there a way to do HEX2DEC in SSRS 2008?

Tags: ssrs-2008

Hello I am working with SSRS 2008. I am wondering if there is a way to do HEX2DEC. I have tried a few things but they get error out. I have tried using HEXTOINT.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Convert.ToInt64 Method directly in the Value expression.

```
=Convert.ToInt64(Fields!MyHexValue.Value,16)
```